# how record canvas video properly, so that output video is supported by all videoplayer

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-mediarecorder

I am recording a html canvas using Media Recorder API, and then upload video to server after that I want to share that video to other apps like WhatsApp using web share API

I am able to record Canvas and upload to server but the duration of video is very small and when I share that video to WhatsApp what share video as distorted

**HERE IS MY CODE TO RECORD CANVAS**

```
    recordBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  recording = !recording;
    if(recording){
            recordBtn.textContent = "Stop";
            const stream = can.captureStream(25);
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
                mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9',
        ignoreMutedMedia: true
            });
            recordedChunks = [];
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = e => {
                if(e.data.size > 0){
          e.target.videoBitsPerSecond=10
         console.log(e)
                    recordedChunks.push(e.data);
                }
            };
      var currentDateTime = new Date();
      startTime=currentDateTime.getTime() / 1000;
            mediaRecorder.start();
        } else {
            recordBtn.textContent = "Record"
            mediaRecorder.stop();
     
            setTimeout(() => {
                const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {
                    type: "video/webm",
          audioBitsPerSecond: 100000,
           videoBitsPerSecond: 4000000
                });
        var currentDateTime = new Date();
      endTime=currentDateTime.getTime() / 1000;
        var duration=endTime-startTime
        console.log(duration)
        ysFixWebmDuration(blob, duration, function(fixedBlob) {
           
            var data = new FormData();
         data.append('file', fixedBlob);
         console.log(data)
         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         data:data,
         contentType: false,
        processData: false,
         url:`http://hthbeats.pythonanywhere.com/file` 
  }).then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    data=data
    
  })
        });

        
                
            },0);
        }
});
```

**HERE IS CODE TO SHARE MEDIA TO OTHER APP**

```
    async function m(){

    
let blob = await fetch("https://hthbeats.pythonanywhere.com/static/t.webm").then(r => r.blob());
console.log(blob)
var file = new File([blob], "t.webm", {type: 'video/webm'});
 const filesArray = [file];
 console.log(filesArray)
 
const shareData = {
  files:filesArray,
  title: 'HTh-Beats',
  text: 'Video sharing ',
  url: "https://hthbeats.pythonanywhere.com/static/t.webm"
}
await navigator.share(shareData)

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let this run for 20 seconds, then you will get the URL of the recorded video in MP4 format.

```js
function Recorder(canvas, fps) {

  var fps = fps || 30;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var videoStream = canvas.captureStream(fps);
  var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(videoStream);

  var videoURL;

  var chunks = [];
  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
  }

  function download(dataurl, filename) {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = dataurl;
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
  }

  mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
    var blob = new Blob(chunks, {
      'type': 'video/mp4'
    });
    chunks = [];
    videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    //console.log("mp4 video url:", videoURL);
    var myReader = new FileReader();
    myReader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    myReader.addEventListener("loadend", function(e) {
      document.getElementById('video').src = e.srcElement.result;
      document.getElementById('canvas').hidden = true;
      document.getElementById('video').hidden = false;
    });
  }

  mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
  }

  this.start = () => mediaRecorder.start();
  this.stop = () => mediaRecorder.stop();
  this.pause = () => mediaRecorder.pause();
  this.resume = () => mediaRecorder.resume();
  this.getUrl = () => videoURL;
  this.download = (fileName) => {
    if (videoURL != "")
      download(videoURL, fileName)
  }
}


/**
 * requestAnimationFrame
 */
window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();


// Configs

var Configs = {
  backgroundColor: '#eee9e9',
  particleNum: 1000,
  step: 5,
  base: 1000,
  zInc: 0.001
};


// Vars

var canvas,
  context,
  screenWidth,
  screenHeight,
  centerX,
  centerY,
  particles = [],
  hueBase = 0,
  simplexNoise,
  zoff = 0,
  gui;


// Initialize

function init() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
  onWindowResize(null);

  for (var i = 0, len = Configs.particleNum; i < len; i++) {
    initParticle((particles[i] = new Particle()));
  }

  simplexNoise = new SimplexNoise();

  canvas.addEventListener('click', onCanvasClick, false);


  rec = new Recorder(canvas);
  setTimeout(rec.start, 100);
  setTimeout(rec.stop, 20000);
  update();
}


// Event listeners

function onWindowResize(e) {
  screenWidth = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  screenHeight = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  centerX = screenWidth / 2;
  centerY = screenHeight / 2;

  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.lineWidth = 0.3;
  context.lineCap = context.lineJoin = 'round';
}

function onCanvasClick(e) {
  context.save();
  context.globalAlpha = 0.8;
  context.fillStyle = Configs.backgroundColor;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
  context.restore();

  simplexNoise = new SimplexNoise();
}


// Functions

function getNoise(x, y, z) {
  var octaves = 4,
    fallout = 0.5,
    amp = 1,
    f = 1,
    sum = 0,
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < octaves; ++i) {
    amp *= fallout;
    sum += amp * (simplexNoise.noise3D(x * f, y * f, z * f) + 1) * 0.5;
    f *= 2;
  }

  return sum;
}

function initParticle(p) {
  p.x = p.pastX = screenWidth * Math.random();
  p.y = p.pastY = screenHeight * Math.random();
  p.color.h = hueBase + Math.atan2(centerY - p.y, centerX - p.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
  p.color.s = 1;
  p.color.l = 0.5;
  p.color.a = 0;
}


// Update

function update() {
  var step = Configs.step,
    base = Configs.base,
    i, p, angle;

  for (i = 0, len = particles.length; i < len; i++) {
    p = particles[i];

    p.pastX = p.x;
    p.pastY = p.y;

    angle = Math.PI * 6 * getNoise(p.x / base * 1.75, p.y / base * 1.75, zoff);
    p.x += Math.cos(angle) * step;
    p.y += Math.sin(angle) * step;

    if (p.color.a < 1) p.color.a += 0.003;

    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = p.color.toString();
    context.moveTo(p.pastX, p.pastY);
    context.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
    context.stroke();

    if (p.x < 0 || p.x > screenWidth || p.y < 0 || p.y > screenHeight) {
      initParticle(p);
    }
  }

  hueBase += 0.1;
  zoff += Configs.zInc;

  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}


/**
 * HSLA
 */
function HSLA(h, s, l, a) {
  this.h = h || 0;
  this.s = s || 0;
  this.l = l || 0;
  this.a = a || 0;
}

HSLA.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'hsla(' + this.h + ',' + (this.s * 100) + '%,' + (this.l * 100) + '%,' + this.a + ')';
}

/**
 * Particle
 */
function Particle(x, y, color) {
  this.x = x || 0;
  this.y = y || 0;
  this.color = color || new HSLA();
  this.pastX = this.x;
  this.pastY = this.y;
}


// Run

init();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #eee9e9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<center><video autoplay hidden=true id='video' width="320" height="240" controls></center>
</video>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/akm2/simplex-noise.js/master/simplex-noise.js"></script>
```

```
rec = new Recorder(yourcanvaselement,FPS); /// fps is optional and defaults to 30.

then:
rec.start()
rec.pause()
rec.resume()
rec.stop()
rec.download("filename.mp4") /// or any name.mp4
to get the recording URL without downloading:
rec.getUrl()
```